# How to pass CSRF Token in JQuery Post request in Rails Application?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, post, csrf

Can any one help me out with passing the CSRF Token while submitting the JQuery AJAX Post Request, Have checked it with Rails was AJAX it Works fine and sends an CSRF Token along with it, but not found any thing with JQuery AJAX Post method.

Please check the below code :

```
$.ajax({ url: 'YOUR URL HERE',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'someData=' + someData,
        success: function(response) {
        $('#someDiv').html(response);
      }
});
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hay,
Have added a simple AJAX code snippet.

Comment: It depends on how the endpoint you're calling expects to receive the CSRF. You'll either need to add it to the `data` you send (which should ideally be an object so that jQuery will encode it for you), or in the headers of the request, which you can use the `headers` property to set. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info on how to do that

Comment: Appreciated your prompt reply..
can you help me with some code snippet that would be really hand and quick for me.

Comment: Ref https://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=118

Answer (score 0):

Use hash and append key in hash as many as you want then pass this hash
 directly in data of ajax request. You will get all these key passed in hash in controller params. Thanks

`data: {someData1: someData1, someData2: someData2}`